# SSH not giving indication that the public key is being used for login

Tags: ssh, password, public-key-authentication

I have a public key to log on to my server. This key is password protected. However, when I log in to my server, there's no indication that the key is ever used. I just log in with my password as before. What kind of messages can I expect using public key/password combined authentication? I just need to know if both are being used or if I botched the public key setup. The client is Xubuntu 14.04, the server is Ubuntu Server 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> ssh -v ...
```

gives you output which tells you how authentication was done. This is with public key:

```
[...]
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /home/hl/.ssh/id_dsa_srm                                                                                                               
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-dss blen 434                                                                                                                      
debug1: Enabling compression at level 6.                                                                                                                                
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).  
[...]
```

That is the technical part. Usually you notice that the public key is used by having to enter the passphrase (unless you don't use one or it is cached by `ssh-agent`).

Comment: @nerdenator You can even force `ssh` to use public keys only. This can be done on the command line or be configured in the config file for certain hosts.